# iOS, no suitable image found / required code signature missing

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, provisioning-profile

I've got several errors (shown below) from my storyboard which I can't solve. I've found several similar issues here and on the web, but nothing I've tried seems to help.

I've even gone back to a backup from several days ago and that seems to have the issue to.

I have installed Xcode 8.1 GM but I haven't access this project with it. I've updated cocoa pods etc.

```
 error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: 
   dlopen(MyFramework.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  
     Did find:
    MyFramework.framework: required code signature missing for 'MyFramework.framework'

 error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of btnCircleGeneral: 
   dlopen(MyFramework.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  
     Did find:
    MyFramework.framework: required code signature missing for 'MyFramework.framework'
```

I've tried deleting derived data / restarting, I am code signing my nested framework already.

My guess is that I've updated something which Xcode 8.1 uses, but is causes issues with Xcode 7.3.1.

I'm not ready to move to Xcode 8 at this time as there seems to a lot of issues with my storyboard.

ANY help appreciated.

Comment: So you have both Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8.1 installed at the same time.  If you are still using the 7.3.1 version as your primary, I would make sure you have set the system to use it as default location (e.g. `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` but replace `/Applications/Xcode.app` part with your Xcode 7.3.1 location.

Comment: @wottle thanks so much for your comment, but sadly my xcode-select setting is correct :( any further advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Phew, uninstalling all versions of Xcode, and every trace of it I could find.
Reboot.
And re-installed Xcode 7.3.1

Seems ok now